# ASP.NET Repeater, ItemCommand takes FOREVER if the repeater has a lot of rows

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm running ASP.NET, I bind the repeater in the pageload with IsNot Postback.  When I fire the ItemCommand, IF the repeater has a couple rows it works great, if the repeater has a lot of rows it just takes forever to process.  How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the Repeater object has its limits. From what I have experienced, there really isn't a way to speed up the repeater's processing and load times.

Comment: Even if I click on something outside of the repeater which is an AJAX update panel, it'll cause that to refresh and the load time is super slow